# Apply extra css class to header when viewing certain page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, asp.net

Got help from a CSS guy to decrease the height of my header if the user scrolls down the page. So instead of a small image and an relating title, leaves just the title, leaving more room to view the webpage. This is done by automatically adding the 'scrolled' class to the header when the user scrolls down the page.

```
<header class="push" style="right: 0px; -webkit-transition: right 300ms ease; transition: right 300ms ease;"
```

to become:
`class="push scrolled"`, which returns to `class="push"` when the user scrolls back up the page, adding the small images to the header again.

My Question being for a particular page I need the header class to be permanently at `class="push scrolled"`. How can I do this?

```
/* change on scroll */
header,
header * {
    -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-in;
    -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease-in;
    -o-transition: all 0.3s ease-in;
    transition: all 0.3s ease-in;
}

header.scrolled {
    padding: 0px 0px 10px 0px;
}

header.scrolled #page-header-top .inner-wrap {
    height: 0;
    padding-top: 0;
    padding-bottom: 0;
}

header.scrolled a#logo {
    margin: 12px 0 5px;
}

header.scrolled ul#nav li a img {
    height: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

header.scrolled #mobile-btn {
    margin: 10px 0 3px;
}
```

Comment: `$("header").addClass("scrolled")`? Is that just it, or am I missing something?

Comment: yeah $("header").addClass("scrolled") works when the page is initially loaded but when i scroll up and down the page again it shows the old larger header....which means it is removing 'scrolled' again?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like your classes are being emptied out with JS which is why it's not holding the class.  Just make sure when it's re-adding the classes to include your scrolled class as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can use another class "collapsable" and apply changes only in ths headers with this class
    $(".collapsable").addClass("scrolled")
Don't add this class to the header you won't to be changed.

You can use id's insted this new class too.